# Drupal 6. Schema API. Удалить таблицу или строку из БД

Tags: drupal, php

Всем доброго времени суток!

Написал модуль для **Drupal 6.33**
...Оформил по всем канонам так сказать.

Проблема в следующем:
В файле **.install**, я создаю свою таблицу через ***hook_schema()***:

```
function my_schema() {
    $schema['name'] = array(
           ...
    );
    return $schema;
}
```

Устанавливаю всё это дело через **hook_install()**:

```
function my_install() {
 drupal_install_schema('my');
}
```

И пытаюсь сгенерировать удаление через ***hook_uninstall()***:

```
function my_uninstall() {
    drupal_uninstall_schema('my');
}
```

Я всё правильно понимаю: если модуль отключить и нажать "*сохранить изменения*", то должен сработать ***hook_uninstall()***?
Если верить **гайду по Drupal**, то ***drupal_uninstall_schema()*** - должна удалять таблицы описанные в ***hook_schema()*** - но почему-то она не удаляет моей таблицы.
Я пересмотрел много примеров с громким названием **"Удаление таблиц из БД Drupal (т.п.)"** и все они используют вот эту фунцию, некоторые примеры я попробовал и результат тот же (таблица жива здорова). Я не правильно понимаю понятие "*Удаление таблицы*"?

Ещё 1н вопрос по удалению строки из таблицы **system**. У неё есть очень вредная привычка сохранять информацию о файле **.module**, что очень препятствует нормальному тестированию модулей. Как избавится в том же ***hook_uninstall()*** и от строки в таблице **system**?

Answer (score 1):

hook_uninstall() вызывается при **удалении** модуля.
Есть две операции:
Отключение модуля, при этом все данных сохраняются, просто модуль не подгружается.
Удаление модуля, при этом выполняется hook_uninstall()

Модуль в друпале сначала отключается, команда drush - drush dis modulename], потом деинсталлируется, команда drush - drush pm-uninstall modulename
В обычной админке сначала модуль нужно отключить, на странице admin/build/modules, потом удалить на появившейся вкладке